# Purpose and usage of GPIO-Hog declaration

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, gpio, device-tree

### Questions

1. What is the purpose and use-case of the `gpio-hog` declaration?
2. Can a 'hogged' gpio pin be interfaced with from Userspace?
3. If a 'hogged' gpio pin cannot be interfaced with from Userspace, then is there any mechanism to configure GPIO pins in the dts file for Userspace interaction?

### Background

I am trying to configure many (10+) GPIOs to speak with a low level chip from Userspace. I have spoken to the chip easily using `sysfs` exports, but both the documentation in the kernel and programming forums have me concerned about using this mechanisms in our production system.

Reading more kernel documentation I read about `gpio-hog` declarations and it seemed like the ideal mechanism to at least initially configure the GPIOs. From the documentation:

> GPIO hogging is a mechanism providing automatic GPIO request and
>   configuration as part of the gpio-controller's driver probe function.

As well as setting the correct low level, vendor settings, I enabled hogging on the desired gpio pins and they came up reporting the correct settings. The problem is that the gpio's are seemingly owned by the kernel and cannot be interfaced with by any Userspace tools such as `sysfs` or `libgpiod`. This makes hogging essentially useless to me and also makes me wonder what it's real purpose is. I am exploring `libgpiod` as a last resort, but the documentation makes it seem that `hogging` should be the mechanism I use.

Comment: *"is there any mechanism to configure GPIO pins in the dts file for Userspace interaction?"* -- For input it's **gpio-keys** that can be read from **/dev/input/eventN** for notification of input transitions. For output it's **leds-gpio**, and controlled by **/sys/class/leds/<name>/brightness**.  See **Documentation/gpio/drivers-on-gpio.txt** for more devices.

Comment: @sawdust, not really -- the `gpio-keys` and `gpio-leds` are intended for using with, well, real keys and real LEDs. Using them for plain logic IO is far from elegant. For example, manipulating a GPIO value via a parameter called `brightness` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JanKundrát very much in agreement.

Comment: @JanKundrát -- The question was for *"any mechanism"*, which I assumed to include quick and dirty methods.  What doesn't make sense IMO is insisting on doing this in userspace.  If you want elegant, then write a kernel driver.

Comment: @sawdust's solution is definitely a stable Q&D fix.  I really have no idea how stable Userspace is because the kernel warns about using it too frequently: `DO NOT ABUSE SYSFS TO CONTROL HARDWARE THAT HAS PROPER KERNEL DRIVERS. PLEASE READ THE DOCUMENT NAMED "drivers-on-gpio.txt" IN THIS DOCUMENTATION DIRECTORY TO AVOID REINVENTING KERNEL WHEELS IN USERSPACE. I MEAN IT. REALLY.` I was hoping for a basic `gpio-out` and `gpio-in` driver that could be extend to have `key` and `led` behavior, but I'll take what i can get for the time being.

Comment: *"I am exploring libgpiod as a last resort"* -- Now that the kernel allows definition of gpio pins in the DT and assigning a name, **libgpiod** is a reasonable choice.  My aversion to userspace is the (old) use of gpio numbers, but if you use a gpio by *name*, then there is a level of abstraction and portability that is almost equivalent to `drivers-on-gpio`.  See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> hog meaning - to take or use a lot of something in a way that prevents other
>   people from having it

so basically gpio-hog property tells the controller to set the pin high/low during bootup, and no other driver/user space would request it.

If you intend to use the gpio in user space you shouldnt be using gpio-hog

Comment: I am just confused at the utility in setting a gpio to a single mode and not being able to use it. Why would anyone use this?

Comment: For one exmaple suppose you want a pin to be  always high/low when booted. But there are  many cases just pick up a Linux  board which you have handy and look at the device tree file of it and then look at the schematics of the board and that will give you more examples.

Comment: It seems sensible to have a way in the device tree to set and lock a pin's direction, but then allow it to be controlled (output) or read (input) by userspace. For an output, it would be useful to be able to set an initial value, but then let it be changed later in userspace. Eg turning on a power-control pin at boot-up.